# Is the close tab in tools timing out?

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, performance

In the 10k-tools when I visit [the close tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Close&daterange=last30days) I get a 500 response in the network trace and the Close votes category stays empty.

Is it timing out (you do notice that selecting [14d](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Close&daterange=last14days), [7d](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Close&daterange=last7days), [2d](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Close&daterange=last2days) or [today](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Close&daterange=today) has noticeable different response times) or are we out of questions with close votes for the last 30days?

Shouldn't we have a visible indication of one of the two outcomes?

Comment: Too many close votes, surprised it worked until now! ;) Anyway the "today" works fine and fast.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-fixed]

Comment: Too bad you didn't nominate yourself so you could status-complete your own questions... :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard I wouldn't be a good mod when I start handling my own questions and answers.. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Can you verify if this is also fixed for you?

Comment: Not fast but no time out either. :)

Comment: self answered assuming is indeed status-fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since February 2014 these timeouts are no longer observed. 
This is confirmed by two separate users.

This bug is either fixed by changes applied due to other features/fixes or it has healed itself.